# Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined for Ionic Push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add Ionic.io Push to my application but its throwing Ionic is not defined

```
ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined
var push = new Ionic.Push({
```

Everything is working fine except this undefined error, I've run this command to update lib but nothing happen, bundle version is * Ionic, v1.1.0

```
ionic lib update
```

My app.js

```
angular.module('TestApp', ['ionic','ionic.service.core',
                            'ionic.service.push',
                            'lavoApp.controllers',
                            'lavoApp.services','ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$location,$timeout,$anchorScroll,$state,$ionicHistory,$cordovaPush) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        var push = new Ionic.Push({
          "debug": true
        });

        push.register(function(token) {
          console.log("Device token:",token.token);
        });
```

Comment: I've had the same problem and been unable to solve it for a while now. Hopefully someone knows how to fix it, my first time working with Ionic so I don't really know what I'm doing!

Comment: @barro32 I created another folder and moved my files templates,js,css files into new project, that worked for me

Answer (score 16):

Just add below line after

```
<script src="lib/ionic/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

in your **index.html** file.

```
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs before you run `ionic io init`. It's also necessary to run `ionic config set dev_push true` right after that if you're running the app in a browser (otherwise you'll get "PushNotification is not defined"). The whole push notification setup procedure is described  [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch).

Answer (score 1):

In following the [setup steps](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/push-limited-setup), Ionic CLI autowrote to my index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

but I had to manually retrieve the source file (ionic.io.bundle.min.js) from:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/master/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js

and put it in the expected directory:

```
lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/
```

I also had to disable and then re-enable limited pushes from the CLI:

```
ionic config set dev_push true
```

Nothing else worked for me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify your ionic-cli version. It has to be the latest, or at least 1.7.10.
check [enter link description here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/issues/10#issuecomment-160639139)

Comment: not version issue, I had latest version there was something else, anyway I solved it by creating another project

Answer (score 0):

Ionic.io(); was supposed to be overruled in the latest version. However, adding Ionic.io(); before var push =Ionic.Push() solved the problem for me. i.e, after i had added the ionic-platform-web-client and push-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general dependency problem! This means somehow your Ionic dependency from bower is not installed correctly. Try to run "bower install" to install all the dependencies again.